# Present progressive. Wie drückt man diese Verbform aus, bitte ohne "gerade"?

Tags: translation, usage, verb-usage

In manchen Büchern sowie in Antworten auf eine ähnliche Frage (R2D2, May 2) kann man lesen, dass man eine Art von "present progressive" mit "gerade" oder "soeben" ausdrücken kann. Zum Beispiel:

> Ich bin gerade am Laufen. Ich laufe gerade. In diesem Moment laufe ich.

Während allerdings die "present progressive" - Form auf Englisch sehr oft erscheint, findet man die Wörter "gerade" und "soeben" in den entsprechenden deutschen Übersetzungen eher selten.

*Es muss daher einige andere Möglichkeiten geben*, die "present progressive" Form auf Deutsch auszudrücken. Können Sie mir bitte sagen, wie Sie diese Verbform übersetzen würden?

Danke.

Comment: also the same question: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/tense-and-aspect

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/i-was-working-in-german/6862#6862

Comment: It has clearly been answered already, hence my close vote

Comment: @Emanuel: Keine der von dir verlinkten Seiten beantwortet die gestellte Frage. Sie befassen sich zwar alle mit diesem Thema, aber wie Present Progressive im Deutschen auf eine andere Weise als unter Zuhilfenahme von "gerade" ausgedrückt werden kann, wurde dort nicht gefragt. Beim Querlesen der Antworten habe ich auch dort nichts gesehen was die hier gestellte Frage beantwortet.

Comment: In allen 3 Threads wird die "am"-Version erwähnt. Und in einem werden auch sprachtheoretische Aspekte diskutiert. Zunächst mal solltest du die Antworten nicht querlesen, sondern lesen. Und dann ist nun mal so, dass, wenn eine Sprache etwas nicht markiert, sie es nicht markiert. End of story. Gerade wird nicht so häufig verwendet wie progressive weil Deutsch an progressiveness einfach nicht so interessiert ist. Nicht weil es irgendwo noch eine geheime Form gibt. Finnish hat keinen Unterschied zwischen "er" und "sie". Es macht keinen Sinn, dann zu fragen "Aber wie macht ihr das denn dann?"

Comment: End of story, wie schön. Man markiert etwas nicht, man kann das nicht ausdrücken. So, die Finnen wissen nicht, wenn sie über einen Mann oder eine Frau sprechen. Wissen das nicht und können das nicht wissen. End of story. Nur weil Finnisch keinen Unterschied zwischen "er" und "sie" haben. Ist es zuviel, danach zu fragen, ob es eine andere Möglichkeit gibt, auf Finnisch das Genus auszudrücken, ohne "er" und "sie"? In meiner Mutterspreche gibt es keinen Unterschied zwischen "gehen" und "fahren", allerdings können wir ohne Zweifel betonen, dass man seine eigene Füsse oder ein Auto dafür verwendet.

Comment: @Calogero... man kann es ausdrücken. Wie man das macht, ist in den 3 Fragen zu diesem Thema beschrieben. Du hast gesagt "Gerade wird nicht so oft benutzt wie Progressive in Englisch". Und dann sagst du "Es muss also eine andere Möglichkeit geben". Und genau das ist falsch. Warum MUSS es noch andere Möglichkeiten geben? Damit Progressive in Deutsch genauso oft markiert ist wie in Englisch? Sprachen haben unterschiedliche Prioritäten und wenn einer Sprache etwas nicht so wichtig ist, dann wird es auch nicht so oft markiert.

Comment: Es gibt aber sprachübergreifend eigentlich immer die Möglichkeit, etwas zu markieren. Und so kennt denn auch das Deutsche eine Reihe von Möglichkeiten, Aspekt zu markieren.

Answer (score 3):

Structurally, the so-called ["Rheinische Verlaufsform"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheinische_Verlaufsform) is nearly equivalent to the English progressive.

- Er ist am arbeiten.

The "gerade" is optional.

Contrary to the name, the Rheinische Verlaufsform is not dialectal; it is grammatical in standard High German (although stylistically dialectal; it is focused on western regions, including Switzerland and the Ruhr region, and is comparatively less typical of Austria and eastern Germany). The main difference between this form and the English progressive is that it is far from the preferred way to talk about such events. So it is perfectly grammatical to say

- Wir gehen zu der Party, wo die Leute gerade am tanzen sind.

But it is *usually* not the preferred way. The simple present is usually preferred, especially when using the respective adverbs, e.g.

- Wir gehen zu der Party, wo die Leute (gerade/im Moment/jetzt) tanzen.

Linguistic note: structurally, the exact status of the Rheinische Verlaufsform is an open research question. However, it [has been argued before that it is indeed a present progressive](http://doktori.bibl.u-szeged.hu/788/1/DISSERTATION_GARGYAN.pdf).

Orthographic note: if the Verlaufsform is indeed a progressive, it should be spelled as in my examples. If it is not, but a regular construction, it should be spelled with the verbal element capitalized:

- Er ist am Arbeiten.

Contemporary speakers disagree on what spelling to use, likely at least in part because they also disagree on if the Verlaufsform actually is a progressive,

Historical note: according to an influential theory by Elisabeth Leiss, aspect used to be marked using case, e.g. often on the article, in Middle German, so that

- er tranc des weins

would, with the object in the Genitive, correspond to imperfective aspect, in contrast to the perfective

- er tranc den wein

Since the rich and flexible case selection system of Old and Middle German was lost in the emergence of New High German, the basic marker of aspect was also lost, without a clear structural way of marking aspect emerging yet.
Adverbial indication of aspect will usually be the best option if context alone is not sufficient.

Comment: [Orthographic note:](http://canoo.net/blog/2011/10/18/wer-am-besten-am-lachen-ist/) if *am* + INF + [*sein*] is considered a regular construct of German (cf. *zu*) the verb should be lowercase, but currently uppercase initial prevails, because the “official” rules are formulated badly and assume a noun after prepositions like *am*.

Comment: This (the relationship between capitalisation and the correct parse of the construction) is correct, I will add it tomorrow  unless anybody else wants to edit it in.

Comment: JFTR: I recently asked the [RSR](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/berichte.html) to add this item to their research agenda. Hopefully, it will make it into their 3rd report, which is due in late 2015 or early 2016, but probably not.

Comment: Die Rheinische Verlaufsform ist keine allgemein gebräuchliche Konstruktion. In Österreich ist diese Form nicht gebräuchlich. Man hört diese Konstruktion dort nur von Migranten und Touristen aus Deutschland. Leuten die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen diese Konstruktion als Standardsprachliche Konstruktion zu verkaufen halte ich für falsch.

Comment: @Crissov: Das Wort "am" ist die Kurzform von "an dem", und "dem" ist ein Artikel. Folglich folgt auf "Jemand ist am" kein Verb, sondern ein Objekt, das in diesem Fall ein substantiviertes Verb ist, und dieses muss groß geschrieben werden. Daher richtig: "Er ist am **Arbeiten**". Falsch: "Er ist am **arbeiten**". Das Prädikat (und zugleich einzige Verb) in diesem Satz ist "ist".

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, dieses *am* (regional auch für *auf dem*) ist nicht dasselbe Wort wie das *am* in der Verlaufsform, vgl. *sie ist zu hören* vs. *sie ist zu Tisch*. Das erste *am* ist übrigens zwar als Kurzform entstanden, kann heute aber nicht mehr in allen Fällen expandiert werden. Es mag auch der Ursprung für das zweite sein, aber **er ist an dem Arbeiten* ist ungrammatisch.

Comment: Die Verbreitung der Rheinischen Verlaufsform nimmt meiner subjektiven Erfahrung nach (in Österreich) leicht zu. (Möglicherweise wegen des Übergewichts privater Fernsehsender mit Standorten im Rheinland?) Aktuelle Daten zur geographischen Verbreitung wären interessant.

Comment: @Hubert Schönlast: ich habe die Antwort insofern angepasst, dass ich nun von Standard*hoch*deutsch spreche, da ich von der österreichischen Situation nichts weiß.

Comment: @jona: Wir Österreicher sind auch nicht gerade eben aus den Ackerfurchen herausgekrochen. Wir sprechen auch Hochdeutsch! Aber die Rheinische Verlaufsform ist gerade erst dabei die Schwelle von einem lokalen Dialekt hinaus auf den ganzen deutschen Sprachraum zu überqueren. Und sie hat diese Schwelle eben noch nicht ganz überschritten. Mich würde ja auch interessieren, wie sehr diese Form in Flensburg, auf Rügen, in Cottbus, in Zwickau, in Passau und in Garmisch-Patenkirchen angewandt wird, also in Städten in Deutschland, die weit weg vom Rheinland sind.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Der Artikel, auf den ich in meiner Antwort verweise, diskutiert auch eine Reihe von Belegen aus österreichischen Zeitungen.

Comment: @jona: Im Wikipedia-Artikel kommen österreichische Zeitungen gar nicht vor. Und hier habe ich ein Zitat aus der verlinkten Doktorarbeit von Seite 152: "In Österreich dagegen ist sie bisher wohl kaum üblich." (sie = Rheinische Verlaufsform). Die meisten der dort zitierten Zeitungsausschnitte sind direkte Reden, also wörtliche Zitate, wobei nicht zu erkennen ist wer da wörtlich zitiert wird. Es könnten Deutsche sein. Weiters muss man die Vorarlberger Nachrichten mit Vorsicht genießen, weil das in Vorarlberg gesprochene Deutsch mehr dem Schweizer Deutsch ähnelt.

Comment: @Hubert Schönlast: Ich habe die Antwort dementsprechend angepasst, dass die Form auf das Westdeutsche konzentriert ist und im Ostdt. und Öst. seltener ist.

Answer (score 2):

Die deutsche Sprache kennt die Zeitform "present progressive" nicht. Deutsch kennt nur eine einzige Form der Gegenwart. Englisch kennt eben zwei verschiedene Formen. Das ist so und das lässt sich nicht ändern.

Wer (so wie ich vor vielen Jahren) als jemand, dessen Muttersprache Deutsch ist, Englisch lernt, hat mit der sogenannten "ing-Form" anfangs ähnlich große Schwierigkeiten wie ein englischer Muttersprachler, der Deutsch lernt und mit den deutschen Artikeln oder den Modalpartikeln nicht klarkommt.

Es macht nicht viel Sinn, darüber nachzudenken, wie man einen englischen Satz, der in der "present progressive tense" verfasst ist, möglichst eins-zu-eins ins Deutsche übersetzen kann. Man kann ja auch nicht die deutschen Artikel oder die vielen Modalpartikeln, die gerade in deutschen Sätzen das Salz in der Suppe sind, beim Übersetzen in die englische Version des Textes hinüberretten.

Die Zuhilfenahme der Wörter "gerade", "soeben", "jetzt" usw. oder Formulierungen wie "Hans ist am Gehen" (statt "Hans geht") sind nur unzulängliche Krücken, um etwas auf eine Weise auszudrücken, die im Englischen zum normalen Sprachgebrauch gehört, der deutschen Sprache aber fehlt.

Das häufige Auftreten dieser Hilfskonstruktionen in deutschen Texten, die aus dem Englischen übersetzt wurden, ist ein Kennzeichen schlechter Übersetzungen, die zu nah am Satzbau des Originals kleben. Man sollte stattdessen versuchen, die Aussage ganz vom Originaltext zu lösen, um sie in der Ziel-Sprache neu zu formulieren.

Die Behauptung »Es muss denn einige anderen Arten davon geben, die "present progressive" Form auf Deutsch auszudrücken.« ist schlichtweg falsch. Nein, es gibt keine anderen Arten. Die deutsche Sprache und die englische enthalten nicht dieselben grammatischen Elemente.

Comment: I disagree with much of this. For example, English has an article system about as rich as German, although not marking for case; English and German articles both code definiteness, number, and can be used deictically. Since the German present is ambiguous wrt. aspect, I do not understand how adverbial marking of aspect can be considered a "Krücke"; that is after all what these words are there for. Furthermore, as I discuss in my own answer, the Rheinische Verlaufsform is likely a progressive.

Comment: @jona: Mit den Artikeln habe ich die drei Genera der Substantive in der deutschen Sprache gemeint (männlich, weiblich, sächlich). Wer aus einer Sprache kommt, wo diese Geschlechter nicht existieren (z.B. Türkisch) oder nur in einer sehr reduzierten Form (z.B. Englisch; alles ist sächlich, nur Personen und personifizierte Dinge sind männlich oder weiblich), hat Probleme das Genus-System der deutschen Sprache zu verstehen. Diese Thema ist aber nicht Thema der gestellten Frage, daher habe ich es auf "Artikel" verkürzt, weil damit den Meisten klar ist was gemeint ist.

Answer (score 0):

Vom direkten übersetzen kann ich nicht viel sagen. Allerdings würde

> Ich laufe.

exakt ausdrücken, dass die sprechende Person in dem Moment des Sprechens läuft. Das *gerade* ist eher umgangsprachlich und "lockert den Satz etwas auf", da nur *Ich laufe* ziemlich steiff klingt.

Comment: This is incorrect. "Ich laufe" by itself does not necessarily ("exakt") mark a currently ongoing event. It could also indicate a promise for a future action ("Wir brauchen Eis? Okay, ich laufe!"), or a habitual event ("Wie ich zur Arbeit komme? Ich laufe."). "Gerade" however forces progressivity (... of something ... compare "Wie komme ich zur Arbeit? Gerade laufe ich.").